# Is it possible to apply CSS to a directive element?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to apply CSS to a directive element but the following example does not work. Any suggestions?

Directive:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'test.html'
    };
});
```

test.html:

```
<div></div>
```

index.html:

```
<body>
    <test></test>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lIZ0VC69fUcDw3G8netN?p=preview):

It's a css issue, just add `display: block;`:

```
test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
```

In HTML, Some tags ( like `div`) get rendered as Block-level Elements by default.
When you create a custom tag it would default to be an inline-element.

Read this article: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

---

You can inspect it inside the developer tools:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link and extra details in the answer.